# How to reference ActiveX ComboBox in Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: excel, activexobject, vba

I've tried various solutions on here and elsewhere such as:

```
dim wb as workbook, ws as worksheet
```

---

```
Dim cb As Object
Set cb = ws.OLEObjects("ComboBoxViews")
```

or

```
ComboBoxViews
```

or

```
ws.comboboxviews
```

But all return Error 1004, the item with specified name wasn't found.  But it DOES exist, checking properties the name is very clearly 'comboboxviews'.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

To make it clear for anyone else seeking help in the future and using Romcel's very helpful code as a base, it seems that in order to add items to an ActiveX ComboBox (which is my final goal), you need to reference it as an object:

```
Sub caller3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim oleob As OLEObject
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each oleob In ws.OLEObjects
  If TypeName(oleob.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
    oleOb.Object.AddItem "TEST"  <<< CORRECT
    oleOb.AddItem "TEST"  <<< INCORRECT
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.comboboxviews` should work, double check `ws` is pointing to the correct sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bluntly refer to your controls in the worksheet like.

```
Sub caller1a()
Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value = "value 1a"    '   no errors
End Sub
```

But you cannot referto them like this.

```
Sub caller1b()
Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Sheet1
  ws.ComboBox1.Value = "value1b"    '  will give error
End Sub
```

If you are familiar with how Excel gives each control their respective index. You can refer to each control as.

```
Sub caller2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Sheet1
  ws.OLEObjects(1).Object.Value = "value2"
End Sub
```

Or just safely loop through them and check if it is the right control you are working with.

```
Sub caller3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim oleob As OLEObject
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each oleob In ws.OLEObjects
  If TypeName(oleob.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
    oleob.Object.Value = "value3"
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!